In SP Online, give contributor level user ability to edit page name (in addition to title)
I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I have a SharePoint Online site with authors (contributor permission level) who publish news articles via the news post feature.
I am attempting to give these users control over the URL slug, and to do so I need to provide them the ability to rename the page name (in addition to page title).
This is what I've done:

I have created a new permission level called News Author, with
permissions as ticked in the linked image.

I then created a new user group called 'News Author Group', and applied
the News Author permission level to it.

I then added the required people to the group.

Lastly, I navigated to
https://sharepoint.com/sites/mypage/SitePages/Forms/AllPages.aspx.
And navigated to Settings > Library Settings > More Library Settings > Permissions and added the group - as confirmed on this page.

When I approach the group, it confirms that it has access to
SitePages.


Yet, the rename option page does not appear, and nor is it possible to edit via the page details pane.
What am I doing wrong???

Unfortunately, this is a default behavior in SharePoint. You need Delete permissions on items/files if you want to rename those.
This behavior corresponds to user's experience on Windows file servers or when users access to a SharePoint web server through Explorer View (WebDAV HTTP protocol extension).
Some related articles

Contributor users are not able to rename items in SharePoint if the Delete permission level is removed from the Contributors group

As a workaround, you can develop Remote Event Receiver to prevent delete with Contribute permission. However Remote Event Receiver is being expired soon. See update at Remote Event Receivers retirement update in SharePoint Online
